# Exporting images as .avi

Tags: export, image-processing, animation

Here's a list of images:

```
images = Table[ExampleData[i], {i, ExampleData["TestImage"]}];
```

And according to the [reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/AVI.html) "Export exports a list of graphics, images, or arbitrary expressions, taking each element to be an animation frame." This is on the reference page for .avi. However,

```
Export["animation.avi", images]
```

causes this:

> Export::errelem: "The Export element !(\"ImageList\") contains a
>   malformed data structure and could not be exported to !(\"AVI\")
>   format."

What's the problem?

(`Export["film.avi", ListAnimate[images]]` works, but I want to know why the above doesn't work...)

Comment: In light of Sjore's answer it is interesting why `Export["film.avi", ListAnimate[images]]` does work?

Comment: Hm... perhaps not. What happens when we export ListAnimate? Basically it's like exporting screenshots of a manipulate-window. All these screenshots have the same size, color channels and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The images have different color spaces, dimensions and image channels. How would you make a movie from that?

```
ImageColorSpace /@ images // Union

(*  ==> {"Grayscale", "RGB"}   *)

ImageDimensions /@ images // Union

(*  ==> {{256, 256}, {512, 512}, {1024, 1024}}  *)

ImageChannels /@ images // Union

(*   ==> {1, 3}  *)
```

You'd have to convert them all to the same format.

```
images2 =  ImageResize[ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"], {256, 256}] & /@ images
```

will do just that. You can now export it:

```
Export["animation.avi", images2, "FrameRate" -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: It might be worth adding a note that one can use `ConformImages` to do the conversion in version 10

Comment: A powerful function, indeed. Good find!

Answer (score 4):

I would guess this is because the images are all of different sizes. For a concrete answer about this, contact technical support at support@wolfram.com with your license number.

In meantime you can create the animation using a Manipulate:

```
Export["animation.avi", 
 Manipulate[images[[i]], {i, 1, Length@images, 1}]]
```