# Formula Formatting is Small and Chunky?

Tags: formatting

I'm sure I'm about to embarrass myself... but, here goes...

I can't read any (but the most basic) typeset formulas in Mathematica. The fonts are simply way too small on my 2560x1440 monitor.

If I make the font sizes bigger, Mathematica seems to simply scale-up the existing formula - making it large enough to be read, but it's ugly-as-sin.

Too small (Mathematica):

[image]

Too ugly (Mathematica):

[image]

What I'm looking for:

## $\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i }{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} y_i} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} ( (\frac{x_i}{y_i})  p ) }{n} $

Comment: Well... _Mathematica_ is not a typesetting engine, so it's probably not going to be as good at kerning as $\LaTeX$ is. You can probably work entirely in `TraditionalForm`, but that's probably not for everyone... You might want to try getting rid of `Courier` though. That's one ugly font.

Comment: @Jens One must necessarily write the fraction out with `Ctrl /` (unless you copy the cell expression) pasting this into mma converts it to $a/b$ when you actually want $\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}$ (there was an old question by Sjoerd on SO about something related to this)

Comment: @R.M Yeah, I just realized that `Courier` is the default font (at least on Mac.) Changing it to a font with serifs helped, but had the kind of issues you suggest it might.

Comment: see, that's why I don't have a 2560x1440 monitor :)

Comment: @R.M. If you paste the code and evaluate it, it will look pretty close to what he had, though. I'll edit it back into my own answer then.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest way to get a slightly more acceptable typeset result is to use `TraditionalForm` as follows, after you enter the expression as in the question:

```
\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(i\)]\)/\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(i\)]\) == \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\((\((
\*FractionBox[
SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(i\)], 
SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(i\)]])\) p)\)\)/n

Magnify[%] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: TraditionalForm]

The reason this doesn't look exactly like what you want is that it wasn't wrapped in `HoldForm`. For more discussion of how to conveniently enter math expressions especially in the context of graphics labeling, see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3296/245).

Here is a better way to enter things, but I better show just the image:

[image: HoldForm]

[image: TradForm]

**Edit 2**

In the other answer I linked above, I mentioned another way to input formulas that actually belongs into the context of this more general question as well. Therefore, I've made a screen capture to illustrate the steps for getting what I think is the closest to a typesetting interface with Mathematica.

The screen movie has to be short because it's a `GIF` animation:

[image: Screencapture]

- I'm starting with the expression typeset in an input cell.
- In the next cell I add `TraditionalForm` content with a dummy string
- The content of the string (`aaa` *inside* the quotation marks) is converted to `TraditionalForm` via the menu
- The original expression is pasted into the invisible `FormBox` that was now created around the `aaa`
- The resulting string can be edited further (e.g., I replace the `==` by `=`, but you can do *arbitrary* edits here)
- With an optional `Magnify` appended, I evaluate the cell and get the desired result

Comment: Thanks! Through some experimentation it looks like Mathematica will automatically reformat using `Times` and with proper italics/non-italics if I do this. That definitely helps.

Comment: @Steve The combination of `HoldForm` and `TraditionalForm` works reasonably well for typesetting. `HoldForm` helps keep things like integrals from being auto-evaluated, and prevents at least some of the rearrangements of the summation signs above...

Comment: Nice work.  How did you make the GIF animation?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Exported from a Quicktime screen capture to `MOV`, then used `ffmpeg` to create frames, selected every `75`-th frame, resized them with `convert` and then used MMA to make the `GIF` with variable "DisplayDurations" to create pauses at the right moments...

Comment: @Jens This should be a question/answer on its own!

Comment: @cartonn Maybe - but the screenshot part is an external process, so it may be a bit off-topic. Anyway, [this other question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6137/245) could be worth mentioning in this context too.

Answer (score 4):

I use a stylesheet with a cell style to display formulas. Then it's just a matter of copying and pasting if you want a formula for display, and you have it in a input cell. Otherwise, enter it in the cell.

Some nice options to put on it are `DefaultFormatType->TraditionalForm` (so your new cells automatically inherit `TraditionalForm` styles), a bigger `FontSize`, perhaps `FontFamily->"Times"`, among others

Comment: +1 but please consider including your stylesheet code.

Answer (score 1):

What about changing from the default Format > Screen Environment > Working to Format > Screen Environment > Presentation? And then perhaps *decreasing* the magnification.