# Retain original form of formatted equation

Tags: hold, output, format

I am having trouble getting Mathematica to retain my original equation form. For example:

[image]

As you can see, even though I use HoldForm, it still changes the style of my equation. Very frustrating.

Comment: You are expecting too much from `HoldForm`. Its only interaction with the front-end is to be treated as an invisible wrapper. It gives the form it wraps no protection from output styling by the front-end. Its protection of the form only extends to preventing evaluation in a kernel.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Conversion of expressions by the FrontEnd](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5617685/590388)."

Comment: I think a possible answer to this is in my response to this question: [Formula Formatting is Small and Chunky?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6164/formula-formatting-is-small-and-chunky)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to enforce fraction on the Boxes level. This is one possible way to do it:

```
SetAttributes[fraction, Attributes@MakeBoxes];

MakeBoxes[fraction[a_, b_], rest_] ^:=
FractionBox[MakeBoxes[a, rest], MakeBoxes[b, rest]]
```

Then you can manually transform subexpressions:

```
fixFractions = # /. Times[a_, Power[b_, -1]] :> fraction[a, b] &;
```

An example:

```
(1 + Sqrt[1+8b(b-1)])/2 // HoldForm // fixFractions // TraditionalForm
```

However, sometimes you might want to leave `Times[_, Power[_, -1]]` as it is. Good news it's not difficult to control with pattern-matching.

**Note:** In this case it works perfectly even without attributes for `fraction`. However, I don't want to remove the `SetAttributes[fraction, Attributes@MakeBoxes]` part, even though I myself don't clearly understand the reasons. Comments on that matter are very welcome.