# Putting label on other side in TimelinePlot

Tags: plotting, formatting, labeling

How to put the label on the other side of the interval.

For instance in the following code, how to push the label **End** on the other hand.

```
displayLaTeX[string_] := 
  DisplayForm[
   ToBoxes@TraditionalForm@ToExpression[string, TeXForm, HoldForm]];
TimelinePlot[{Interval[{DateObject[{2015, 6, 1}], 
     DateObject[{2016, 2, 29}]}] -> "End "}, AxesOrigin -> Center, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image]

Courtesy of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108548/3066) given by [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens).

Comment: I can not make out from your question how you want to change what you have now. Could you please show the result you want?

Comment: The label 'End' is at June in above. I want to put that label at March. i-e there are two extremes of the interval, then how to move the label from one extreme to another extreme?

Answer (score 3):

It is simply a matter of getting the date objects into a sensible grouping, getting the labels attached to the right date objects, and removing the option `AxesOrigin -> Center`.

```
TimelinePlot[
  {{Interval[{DateObject[{2015, 1, 15}], DateObject[{2015, 9, 9}]}]},
   {DateObject[{2015, 6, 1}] -> 
      Row[{"Start ", displayLaTeX["\\sum_{i=0}^{10} f(x_i)"]}],
    Interval[{DateObject[{2015, 6, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 2, 29}]}],
    DateObject[{2016, 3, 6}] -> "End "}, 
   {Interval[{DateObject[{2016, 7, 27}], DateObject[{2016, 8, 6}]}]}},
  PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image: plot]

As far as I can determine, bubble labels can only be placed on point events or at the start  of time lines. Therefore, I think what you asking for can not done. Perhaps someone more knowledgable will prove me wrong.

Therefore, you can have this:

```
TimelinePlot[
  {{Interval[{DateObject[{2015, 1, 15}], DateObject[{2015, 9, 9}]}]}, 
   {Labeled[
      Interval[{DateObject[{2015, 6, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 2, 29}]}], 
      Row[{"Start ", displayLaTeX["\\sum_{i=0}^{10} f(x_i)"]}]],
    Labeled[DateObject[{2016, 3, 6}], "End"]}, 
   {Interval[{DateObject[{2016, 7, 27}], DateObject[{2016, 8, 6}]}]}}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image: plot2]

You can also have a time line with standard labels as follows:

```
TimelinePlot[
  {{Interval[{DateObject[{2015, 1, 15}], DateObject[{2015, 9, 9}]}]}, 
   {Labeled[
      Interval[{DateObject[{2015, 6, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 2, 29}]}], 
      {Row[{"Start ", displayLaTeX["\\sum_{i=0}^{10} f(x_i)"]}], "End"}, 
      {Before, After}]}, 
   {Interval[{DateObject[{2016, 7, 27}], DateObject[{2016, 8, 6}]}]}}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image: plot3]

Comment: I have edited the question. There was ambiguity.

Comment: The points are disconnected from the actual interval, so it is not exactly I need.

Comment: The last option you provided might help me.