# How to scale the parenthesis like how the LaTeX \left \right commands do?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting, style, traditional-form

I am trying to use `Graphics[Text[]]` to label some curves on a plot. However, I cannot format the text properly.

I want my text to look like this

$$F= \left(\dfrac{2\tilde\omega}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^\frac{3}{2}$$

but it looks like this

$$F= (\dfrac{2\tilde\omega}{\sqrt{3}})^\frac{3}{2}$$

Here is my code.

```
Graphics[{Text[
   Style["F=(\!\(\*FractionBox[\(2\\\ \*OverscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \
\(\[Tilde]\)]\), SqrtBox[\(3\)]]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \
FractionBox[\(3\), \(2\)]]\)", FontSize -> 15, 
    FontFamily -> "CMU Serif", Purple], {2.4, 0.755}]}]
```

I'm adding a screenshot here because I don't know how to format Mathematica code on this website.

[image]

This is the output of my code.

[image]

Comment: @Nasser's answer is excellent. There is a sort of dirty hack that you can use: inline cells. If you're in a "context" that is not the standard input (e.g. a Text cell or just within a string), you can do a Control-9 to get a little inline cell where the cursor was. You an do pretty much everything to this little cell as you can with a regular cell. So, you can start with Text[""], put your cursor between the  quotes, do Control-9, and create the expression you wanted (using the Palettes is a nice way to do this). Once it looks as you want, you can insert it into your Graphics. Kind of a hack.

Comment: @lericr Side note: seems that the Ctrl+9 short cut won't work in a Wolfram lanuage input cell if the format of cell is `InputForm` at least in windows, _v12.3.1_. (One can switch to `InputForm` by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I, and switch back to the default `StandardForm` by pressing Ctrl+Shift+N. )

Comment: All you need to do is enter the text in the string as `TraditionalForm` as I did [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6165/245)

Comment: @Jens Oh, Why I forgot about Ctrl+Shift+T… Post this as an answer? This is the best solution so far.

Comment: @xzczd OK - I added an answer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

May be

```
text = HoldForm[F = ((2*OverTilde[\[Omega]])/Sqrt[3])^(3/2)]; 
Graphics[{Text[
   Style[text, FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "CMU Serif", 
    Purple], {2.4, 0.755}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Another option is to use MaTeX directly to make these labels. Like this

```
<< MaTeX`

text = MaTeX[
   "F=\\left( \\frac{2 \\tilde{\\omega}}{\\sqrt 3} \
\\right)^{\\frac{3}{2}}", Magnification -> 2];
Graphics[{Text[text, {2.4, 0.755}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Color can be added also if needed. `Text` above is used just to put the MaTeX output at correct location since the output is not really text in this case but an image rendering.

Comment: I'll second that recommendation for using *MaTeX* when elegant typography is essential.  (My hope is that Wolfram Research buys *MaTeX* from Szabolcs Horvát, as he deserves compensation for his great work, and that $\LaTeX$-style typography gets fully integrated with the *Mathematica* kernel.  But who knows?)

Comment: Mathematica has native $\LaTeX$ capabilities, which are not complete, but I have built a lightweight wrapper around it that works in most simple cases. It has the advantage that it is formatted text and not an image. I have only tested it on version 11.3. If someone is willing to test it on later versions, I can post it here.

Answer (score 11):

Use the SpanMaxSize option on each parenthesis.

```
Graphics[{Circle[], Text[DisplayForm[FormBox[
   Style[RowBox[{"F", "=", 
       SuperscriptBox[
         RowBox[{StyleBox["(", SpanMaxSize -> Infinity], 
            FractionBox[
              RowBox[{"2", " ", "\[Omega]"}], 
              SqrtBox["3"]], 
       StyleBox[")", SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]}], 
         RowBox[{"2", "/", "3"}]]}], FontSize -> 15, 
  FontFamily -> "CMU Serif", Purple], TraditionalForm]]]}]
```

[image]
A more efficient method would be to change the notebook options so that you don't have to use the code every time.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the new-in-*12.2* inline $\LaTeX$ cell. (The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.) First generate the $\LaTeX$ code with `TeXForm`:

```
TeXForm@Unevaluated[F = ((2 OverTilde@ω)/Sqrt@3)^(3/2)]
(* F=\left(\frac{2 \tilde{\omega }}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{3/2} *)
```

Alternatively, select the code and right click and select **Copy As**▶**LaTeX**, or simply type it manually. Then

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I answered a related question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6165/245), and the method really applies almost anywhere you might want to enter nicely formatted maths in a notebook: In the string, type a single dummy letter, then highlight that letter and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-T to turn that letter into `TraditionalForm` (it's <kbd>Command</kbd> on Mac and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Windows; you can also go to the menu Cell > Convert To > TraditionalForm). Then go back and change the dummy letter into the math expression you want. Parentheses will extend with their content as expected. You can see how I do this in the screen capture at the end of my linked post.