# What in Mathematica is equivalent to GetFrame in Matlab?

Tags: plotting, animation, frame

I am going to develop an unsteady diffusion calculation in Mathematica. Because it is unsteady, I would like to visualize the solution each time step (or in some time steps). My MATLAB skills are much better than Mathematica, so I am going to give the example from there. I looked at some of the posts about that, but they were for small number of time steps like 10, or saving each plot and creating a movie. But in MATLAB I can do

```
surf(x,z,U_sol)
F=getframe;
```

`x` and `z` are the position vectors and `U_sol` is the solution matrix. `GetFrame` simply preserves frame but not the plot, so it looks like a continuous plotting, like a movie.

In Matlab, you can do something like this to save the movie directly. This is before time steps

```
fid=figure;
pos=get(fid,'position');
writerObj=VideoWriter('sol.avi');
writerObj.FrameRate=10;
open(writerObj);
```

and inside the time loop

```
 PLOT...
 frame=getframe(gcf);
 writeVideo(writerObj,frame)
```

and at the end of the time loop.

```
 close (writerObj)
```

and you will have the movie file without dealing with each frame. There should be some equivalent version in Mathematica.

Comment: I guess you want `ListPlot3D[]` (or `Plot3D[]` if you're using `NDSolve[]` for the PDE), `Animate[]`, and/or `Export[]`...

Comment: mathematica can not `Export` on a frame by frame basis, you need to compile all frames as a list and `Export` all at once.

Comment: I am not using NDSolve. I use my own code and every time step I create a solution which I want continuously plot without recreating the frame and ideally save them while plotting them. But it seems I need to save each frame but that is really inefficient if you have 10000 or more steps.

Comment: if you want to watch the frames as the solution proceeds have a look at `Monitor`

Comment: If you are on Windows you can use my [MathMF package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46813/862) to write frames one by one to a video stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica can't build a writer object (in fact it doesn't have proper objects at all, excluding the front-end) but you can always build your snapshots in a temporary directory. Give this a go:

```
movieDir = CreateDirectory[];
getFrame[plot_, tag_] := 
  Export[FileNameJoin@{movieDir, ToString[tag] <> ".png"}, plot];
getImages[] := 
  Import /@ 
   SortBy[FileNames["*.png", movieDir], ToExpression@FileBaseName@# &];
createMovie[file_] :=
  With[{images = getImages[]},
   With[{dims = ImageDimensions@First@images},
    Export[file,
     ImageResize[ColorConvert[#, "RGB"], dims] & /@ images
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

Note the manipulations done to the images in `createMovie`. That's to get around the issues mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5594/exporting-images-as-avi).

Then we can build our plots and images:

```
In[458]:= (Do[
   getFrame[Plot[Sin[s*x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], 
    IntegerPart[10*s]],
   {s, 0, 2, .1}
   ];
  createMovie["~/Desktop/sol.gif"]) // AbsoluteTiming

Out[458]= {3.2397, "~/Desktop/sol.gif"}
```

And what we get is this (note that .avi works too, I just used .gif so I could embed it here):

[image: visualization gif]

Comment: Thank you ..this is what  I was trying to do.